# Qu'entend votre communauté par "français correct" ?

Tags: discussion, prescriptivism, descriptivism

([Cette question](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/7167/pourquoi-distinguable-avec-un-u) est suggérée par un désaccord qui m'a coûté deux points, sur l'orthographe de *distinguable* - ma position étant que c'est un barbarisme inutile et que la question ne se posait donc pas, puisque le français a déjà "distinct" et "distinctif")

**Dire que tel terme ou phrase est correct, ou non, suppose que l'on ait des critères. Pourriez-vous donc expliciter les vôtres ?**

Je soumets les miens, compendieusement, à votre sagacité.

1- Tous les niveaux de langage sont admissibles, dans le contexte adéquat, de l'argot gouailleur de San Antonio à la maîtrise parfaite et la précision de pensée de Bossuet. Et pourquoi pas des innovations à la Queneau ou celle du "nouveau roman" ; le temps est le meilleur critique de ce qui mérite de subsister.

2- Je déteste les fautes dues à l'ignorance, comme "par ailleurs" (= par une autre voie, et non "de plus"), "alternative" (= choix entre deux, et deux seulement, possibilités), "par contre" (terme commercial signifiant : en compensation, ou abréviation de "par contre-envoi" - on dit maintenant par retour de courrier-, et non "en revanche"), "antan" (= de l'année dernière et non "jadis"), etc..
Le nombre de voix des ignorants et des paresseux ne doit pas apprécié à la majorité démocratique ou plutôt médiocratique. Il y a déjà bien des dégâts irréparables, comme le pléonastique "aujourd'hui" ou le monstrueux "qu'est-ce que c'est que ...".

3- Et tout autant l'inertie de l'Académie (ils sont quarante qui ont de l'esprit comme quatre, disait Piron - et dont beaucoup n'ont ni formation universitaire, ni ouvrages significatifs à leur crédit), qui met un quart de siècle avant de terminer une nouvelle version de son dictionnaire, et ne respecte même pas ses propres critères (orthographe selon l'étymologie, prononciation selon l'usage : "bonhomie" et "gageure", alors ?). Prononciation de quel lieu, d'ailleurs ? La langue française n'appartient plus qu'à la seule France métropolitaine.

Ni les puristes, qui décrètent que "second" ne peut s'employer en énumérant plus de deux choses, qu'il faut dire "deuxième", ou que "à cause que" n'est pas français - tiens, mais pourquoi donc ? Lire ce qu'écrivait par exemple Vaugelas est risible, et heureusement les classiques ne l'ont pas écouté, sauf un peu Corneille, pour plaire à Richelieu.

4- Enfin, je n'aime guère les dictionnaires commerciaux, rédigés par des auteurs qui n'ont peut-être pas tous les qualifications requises et sont bien en peine d'expliquer pourquoi ils admettent ou suppriment un mot ; en fait, ils suivent l'usage, le but est de publier à chaque fin d'année un nouvel exemplaire daté de l'année suivante, que les naïfs vont s'arracher. Même les prix littéraires sont attribués en fonction des rivalités des éditeurs.

5- Qu'il y a-t-il de positif donc ?

Je crois que le bon français est formé par les bons auteurs, qui en comprennent l'essence, sont suffisamment cultivés pour ne pas aller contre l'esprit ni l'étymologie, ni non plus commettre de fautes, et assez imaginatifs pour avoir des hardiesses. L'exemple extrême est celui des œuvres attribuées à Shakespeare, où le tiers du vocabulaire a été forgé, beaucoup de nouvelles tournures y ont fait leur apparition, et beaucoup de tout cela a survécu jusqu'à nos jours.

Et qu'il faut se fier à eux, et à eux seuls.

Mon rêve fou ? Que de nouveaux grands auteurs apparaissent, qui maîtrisent parfaitement le français classique, mais assez larges d'esprit pour admettre dans leurs écrits des termes et des tournures qui ne soient pas seulement métropolitains, ressuscitent des mots oubliés (quel besoin de "badge" quand le français avait "affiquet" ?), et en inventent de nouveaux qui font défaut.
Il est surprenant que, généralement pour "faire tendance", on doive emprunter à l'anglais (j'adore les deux langues, mais pas le Frenglish), dont les deux tiers du vocabulaire viennent du français, mais qui a su, lui, conserver des milliers de mots qui disparaissaient de celui-ci, et maintenant font défaut. Pourquoi ne pas récupérer le butin ?

**Opinions très personnelles et tranchées, voire acerbes ; merci de vos réactions.**

Comment: Je suis tout nouveau sur votre site (dix jours), et n'en ai pas encore pénétré toutes les arcanes.

Comment: Méta est la place pour les discussions et questions au sujet de tout ce qui touche à ce site et à sa communauté.

Comment: À l'heure du jour d'aujourd'hui, je me dois de faire la constatation de la dangerosité du mauvais parler et il faut palier à ce fléau en prévoyant en avance.

Comment: Je serois le plus fâché du monde, Monsieur Impair, que de votre discours je ne pusse point tenir à prix l'ironie. :)

Comment: Merci à "Un francophone" de son lien - la mise en boîte, dans une intervention, est désopilante, et surtout met en garde contre le danger de se prendre trop au sérieux.

Comment: Sans avoir aucun lien financier avec l'éditeur, le petit Robert est l'outil le plus efficace pour aider à parler un *français correct* et contemporain. C'est un choix 'politique' éditorial où l'amour de la langue passe avant l'intérêt mercantile que j'ai rarement retrouvé chez ses confrères qu'il m'est arrivé de feuilleter. Il m'aide très souvent à donner sur Fl&U des réponses précises ou motivées.

Comment: @Zistoloen apparemment oui, mais réellement **non** car la qualité du texte en fait une expérience valable pour ceux qui veulent découvrir le français, et, il leur permet d'appréhender leurs futures difficultés ; choses qui leurs seront invisibles sur *meta* si l'on retire ce texte qui souligne la complexité d'une langue.

Comment: Notre question de référence sur le sujet : [Prescriptivist vs. descriptivist / Prescriptif ou descriptif](http://meta.french.stackexchange.com/questions/11/prescriptivist-vs-descriptivist-prescriptif-ou-descriptif)

Comment: En réponse à cl-r : je ne peux que reconnaître de grands mérites à Alain Rey, qui vient d'avoir 85 ans, mais enfin je me suis laissé dire que le Robert est actuellement rédigé, en fait, par deux personnes seulement ; comment avoir une culture tellement étendue qu'elle permette d'apprécier chaque mot en connaissance de cause ? Et l'idée d'adopter des mots à la mode, même du verlan, n'est pas bonne, c'est déjà ringard à peine publié. Littré prétendait bien avoir travaillé seul, c'est humainement impossible de savoir tant de dialectes, de trouver tant de citations à 62 printemps.

Comment: +1 pour *affiquet*. Il est très rigolo, je vais le placer.

Comment: Concernant l'emprunt à l'anglais, travaillant dans l'informatique et intéressé par les nouvelles technologies, je constate effectivement que nous empruntons beaucoup, pour diverses raisons. Parce que l'anglais est la langue utilisée pour la plupart des nouveautés en premier lieu et que souvent ces nouveautés sont retranscrites telles quelles, avec un taux d'adoption trop élevé pour que les traductions proposées des mois plus tard entrent dans les mœurs. 1/2

Comment: Ensuite parce que nombre des traductions sont plus complexes/longues/... Lorsque vous faites du séquençage génétique et que vous parlez de vos lectures à longueur de journée, une syllabe peut tout changer et vous choisissez d'utiliser _read_. Ceci est en outre renforcé par la mondialisation : les informaticiens communiquent à travers le monde, les chercheurs publient leurs articles en anglais dans l'espoir de maximiser leur exposition, ... L'anglais est « la langue universelle », et il est plus simple d'adopter ses mots que de trouver des expressions équivalentes mais plus lourdes. 2/2

Comment: (J'aime beaucoup tes propositions. En revanche, je suis maniaque (au-delà de ton puriste) sur certains points, dont la typographie. Les guillemets français sont quelque chose à quoi je tiens. :) Certes (trop) difficilement accessibles sur nos claviers.)

Answer (score 8):

Pour faire une réponse courte à une question longue (mais excellemment posée, et pertinente me semble-t-il), je crois que le meilleur compromis que nous ayons, et que je vois pratiqué très régulièrement ici, est de dire **où, quand, et pour qui** telle ou telle tournure est correcte.

Cela permet de s'affranchir d'un jugement définitif, que l'on a l'élégance de laisser au lecteur. La question que tu poses sur cette page, ce n'est pas à nous d'y répondre une bonne fois pour toutes, c'est à chaque lecteur d'y répondre implicitement, à chaque question lue. Cela n'empêche pas, bien entendu, d'exprimer un jugement de valeur personnel *en complément*, si cela enrichit le propos.

Un exemple : quelqu'un pose la question : **Est-il correct de dire "J'ai trop kiffé ma race"?** (exemple posté aujourd'hui.... [ici](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/13589/can-you-use-je-kiffe-in-exams))

On pourra, plutôt qu'un péremptoire *ce n'est pas correct*, dire que cette forme est considérée comme correcte (ou non) par telle ou telle instance de la langue (avec références si besoin), qu'elle est courante, rare ou inexistante à telle époque / à tel endroit, ou encore qu'elle est propre à un registre de langue ou à un autre. Toutes ces informations permettent d'avoir une compréhension du point de langue en question, sans l'enferrer dans une hypothétique *correction formelle*...

---

**En résumé**, on pourrait dire que *le français correct* est une expression trop incomplète pour désigner quoi que ce soit.

Comment: Votre relativisme est très sage ; mais un cadre normatif général est nécessaire. Je parle le français de Paris-Ouest et l'anglais de West-London, grâce à quoi je suis compris partout ; l'inverse n'est pas vrai, j'ai parfois des difficultés au Québec, en Australie, et même en Angleterre du Nord.

Comment: (suite, j'ai été coupé par le temps limite) Je ne dirais pas que le particularisme puisse être une question individuelle, sinon, comment communiquer ? Mais il est normal que chaque corps de métier, chaque groupe ethnique ait une langue dérivée (pidgin, créole, yiddish, etc.). "Je kiffe ma meuf" est normal entre Imazighen ("Berbères" et non Arabes ; le singulier est Amazigh). Hors de ce milieu, c'est de l'ostentation, pour faire "trendy".

Answer (score 7):

J'ai cessé de me battre contre ces moulins-là, d'abord parce que pour cela il faut soi-même être irréprochable, ensuite parce que la limite entre le 2 et le 3 option puriste est assez floue: pourquoi par exemple alternative exigerait exactement deux options quand l'étymologie évoque seulement *autre* et quand même les bons auteurs peuvent être surpris à déroger à la règle?

Et puis définir le bon français d'après les bons auteurs est une démarche qui se mord la queue. Comment reconnaît-on un bon auteur? En ce qu'il s'exprime en bon français? Est-ce que San Antonio est un bon auteur? Et Brassens, qui n'hésite pas à évoquer les neiges d'antan en pensant plus loin que l'an passé? Est ce que le seul bon dictionnaire est celui d'Emile Littré parce qu'il s'appuie sur les auteurs qu'il estimait bons?

Sans compter que le français ne vit pas que par les bons auteurs. J'ai envie de profiter de la créativité de la rue aussi, celle qui injecte la richesse de tous les argots et de toutes les langues. Je kiffe!

Cela dit, je comprends l'interrogation quand on est abreuvé de *reculades*, *bravitudes* et autres inventions médiatico-politiques du microcosme parisien. Ici un peu de recul et le temps sont les meilleurs filtres.

Comment: Personne n'est irréprochable, et je ne voulais pas insinuer que je le fusse, dans des affirmations incisives qui sont en fait l'expression de doutes.

Comment: Le *français correct* ne se défini pas par le mental mais par l'expérience que l'on en a ; ce qui revient à dire qu'il faut un dictionnaire (les mots) mais que la grammaire n'est pas suffisante, d'autant plus qu'elle peut se déduire de l'expérience, elle vient seulement vérifier qu'il n'y a pas d'exception accepté par les usages en cours.

Comment: L'étymologie, évidemment latine, de "alter" impose deux et seulement deux possibilités. Si vous êtes bricoleur, ne confondez pas courants alternatif et triphasé. Il me semblait implicite que pour moi un bon auteur est celui qui sait déjà bien sa langue, l'enrichit d'innovations, et demeure plus que perenne (= qui survit une année). Mais oui, Frédéric Dard était un bon auteur ! L'ouvrage de Littré est remarquable, mais pas, ni plus, unique.

Comment: @cl-r - Même le dictionnaire ne suffit pas, sinon d'où viendraient les néologismes?

Comment: @MarkThorin - Le courant triphasé est alternatif, c'est juste que les alternances entre plus et moins sont décalées dans le temps. Quant aux bons auteurs, une de mes réserves à leur sujet serait de n'accorder qu'à eux le droit d'enrichir la langue. Même l'ignorance peut être source de créativité. Je pense par exemple à un étranger qui ne maîtrise pas le français et qui est obligé d'utiliser une image ou un mot pour un autre pour exprimer sa pensée.

Comment: @mouviciel J'ai bien préciser + l'expérience : connaître les sons d'une langue et comment l'oreille les décode ; pour la réponse à Mark : il s'agit aussi du français que l'on retrouve en Afrique, où la poésie des images remplace l'exactitude d'un mot aux racines grecques ou latines.

Answer (score 2):

Il me semble que le bon français est une notion qui existe, mais dont il faut se méfier.

La langue sert avant tout à communiquer avec autrui, tout le reste est secondaire, y compris Shakespeare (et Molière). Si les gens se comprennent par SMS, quel est le problème ?

Je pense qu'il est vain, et erroné, de prendre les choses par la qualité de la langue : il faut les prendre par l'intérêt, la séduction, l'enrichissement humain... découvrir la richesse humaine d'abord, le reste viendra.

Peut être connaissez vous les assemblées évangéliques (moi je n'en suis pas un mais j'ai fréquenté un peu) ; j'ai été étonné de voir qu'on y pratiquait un parlé assez riche, alors que les textes sont assez pauvres ; c'est parce que (mon interprétation) ils pratiquent beaucoup d'oral, dans diverses situations, et réfléchissent beaucoup à l'écrit, même si cet écrit n'est pas toujours super.

(pour les textes assez pauvres, plus exactement, si la Bible est un livre extraordinaire, les interprétations qu'en font les évangéliques sont assez pauvres) (de mon opinion)

C'est pareil dans les milieux administratifs ; il y a des textes règlementaires qui sont étonnamment bien écrits (mais malheureusement je n'en ai pas sous la main) (il me semble que Yves Bonnefoy est un fonctionnaire à la base ? )

Il faut viser premièrement la pratique, le jeu, la fluidité ; de là vient le gout de parler, de communiquer autrement que les platitudes habituelles, puis l'interêt pour la littérature, la chanson, le cinéma, la bande dessinée, etc, et le gout des grands auteurs.

Mais si vous commencez par les grands auteurs, c'est peine perdue, sauf hasard heureux.

Enfin, pour le "bon français", je pense que les choses se passent aujourd'hui au niveau de la francophonie plus que de la France. C'est plus à ce niveau qu'il faut réfléchir, et où se trouve d'extraordinaires talents.

Comment: Je ne visais que les réponses aux questions du genre "... est-il correct ?". Bien entendu, il y a bien d'autres moyens de communication qu'une langue employée correctement, y compris avec les animaux.

Answer (score 1):

**Une saine colère !**

... contre soi-même qui se révolte contre toute autorité issue de la cooptation.

et un magnifique mouvement créatif dû à une bonne santé francophone, libre comme il se doit !

L'intuition à l’œuvre dans la perception de la francophonie débuche les faux-semblants, les mauvaises habitudes, les séquelles mercantiles auxquelles s'ajoute une fière tradition révolutionnaire de dé-centralisation inhérente à l'évolution de la pensée sous-jacente.

Et puis le mouvement se résorbe, ... que reste-t-il ?

**Le rêve**

... qui n'est jamais fou, qui est la porte que la conscience laisse ouverte pour exprimer ses besoins d'apaisement.

Il faut donc y entrer, sans peur ni vouloir, sans honte ni savoir.

Alors le chant des poètes, des créatifs et des sources du langage murmure ses envies.

Le retour aux sources communes à tous se passe avant la formulation même du langage, au niveau de la vibration des mots qui développent leur musique.

Vient ensuite le contrôle de la mémoire qui nettoie les scories, valide, embellit les idées pour les communiquer.

Alors oui, *un français correct*, celui de la francophonie, se traduit en une 'franco-scriptie', danse de caractères sur une ligne qui réjouit ou apaise le lecteur.

Point besoin de plume besogneuse lorsque l'écoute de la musique est sincère, loyale, entière.

Un mouvement perpétuel de ré-invention se vit, dans ce jaillissement francophone aux cycles infinis.

Laissez-le s'épanouir dans son libre parcours, vos lecteurs s'en feront l'écho.

Comment: Très belle réponse, merci.